#  How can I create an HTML button that copies selected text to the clients clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard

Here's a screenshot of my use case:

[image]

Where the button is just a `<button>Copy To Clipboard</button>` element.

What's the best way to accomplish this? I'm using jQuery.

I'm only concerned of having it work on modern browsers, and if it works on IE8> it's an added bonus, but not 100% required.

Comment: Cross browser clipboard copying (without permissions) can be done in flash, but needs to be triggered with a user interaction such as a click event.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I'm open to alternatives, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most cross-browser implementations use Flash to get past security restrictions. AFAIK, there isn't a W3C standard for accessing the system pasteboard.

I've used [Clippy](https://github.com/mojombo/clippy) in the past. It's lightweight and fast and does just what it says on the box.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.dynamic-tools.net/toolbox/copyToClipboard/) seems to offer the code to do this:

```
function copyToClipboard(s)
{
    if( window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData )
    {
        clipboardData.setData("Text", s);
    }
    else
    {
        // You have to sign the code to enable this or allow the action in about:config by changing
        user_pref("signed.applets.codebase_principal_support", true);
        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');

        var clip Components.classes['@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;[[[[1]]]]'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);
        if (!clip) return;

        // create a transferable
        var trans = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;[[[[1]]]]'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);
        if (!trans) return;

        // specify the data we wish to handle. Plaintext in this case.
        trans.addDataFlavor('text/unicode');

        // To get the data from the transferable we need two new objects
        var str = new Object();
        var len = new Object();

        var str = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;[[[[1]]]]"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);

        var copytext=meintext;

        str.data=copytext;

        trans.setTransferData("text/unicode",str,copytext.length*[[[[2]]]]);

        var clipid=Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard;

        if (!clip) return false;

        clip.setData(trans,null,clipid.kGlobalClipboard);      
    }
}

<textarea id='testText'>#COPYTOCLIPBOARD CODE#</textarea><br>
<button onclick='copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('testText').value);'>
```

Apparently Mozilla based browser will ask for permission to do this but I don't think that is avoidable.